# Automatic focus on next edittext for digit password entry

Tags: android-widget

From my app, I expect more like that implemented on IPhone with four digits for password entry, which means with masked dot. I'm already done with the correct entry. Using the concrete implementation for TextWatcher in `addTextChangedListener`, however, when I entered 4 wrong digits and the focus was returned back to the first one and every digit was cleared as well. In this case, the original soft keyboard for digit input switched back to the qwert one and any letter or digit entered became visible without masking with dot.

```
myEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(mPasswordEditText){
       @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            s = mPasswordEditText.getText();
            int cacheH = UnlockScreen.this.mPasswordEditText.getHeight();
            if(s.length() == 1){
                UnlockScreen.this.mPasswordEditText1.requestFocus();
                    mPasswordEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    mPasswordEditText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    mPasswordEditText.setMinHeight(cacheH);
            }                   
        }
});
```

But it didn't work well as expected. 
XML layout is:

```
           <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/unlock_screen_password_edittext_1"
                    style="@style/passcodeStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".20"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:digits="@string/digits_only"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:maxLength="1"/>
```

Any idea, folks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using setText(s.toString().replace(s.toString(), '.')); instead of mPasswordEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);and                    mPasswordEditText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
And set flags for textChange status in each edittext.
I'm not sure it's the best solution but for my app, this works fine and so far I've had no idea of a better way.